# Markov chain - is my diagram/matrix correct?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

A boy goes to school on a bike or on foot.

If one day he goes on foot, then on the second day he takes a bike with probability $0.8$.

If he goes on a bike one day, then he falls off the bike with probability $0.3$ and goes on foot the next day.

What is the probability that one the last day of school he goes to school on a bike?

We assume that the school year has just started.

I can see that we need to define a Markov chain.

I've tried coming up with a directed graph which I cannot draw here, but I've pasted it here [image]

This is what the matrix would look like:

$$A= \begin{array}{l}
\mbox{bike} \\
\mbox{falls}  \\
\mbox{on foot}  \\
\mbox{doesn't fall}
\end{array} \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.7 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0.8 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right) $$

This matrix is ergodic and solving the equation $[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4]A = [x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4], \ \ x_1 + x_2  + x_3 +x_4=1$ I get that $x_1=8/19$.

So it would seem that the probability that on the last day of school the boy travels on a bike is $8/19$.

Is that true? Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify things a lot by just using two states, foot (state $1$) and bicycle (state $2$). Then you have the transition matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix} 0.2 & 0.8 \\ 0.3 & 0.7 \end{pmatrix}$$

In fact, the way you've done it is a bit confusing because falling off a bicycle is not a *state* in the same sense that going to school by foot/bicycle is. For one time step (a day) his state is the mode of transport he uses. But he doesn't spend a full day falling off a bike, so it doesn't make sense to use this as a state.

Comment: Oh, you're right. The numbers are clear to me :) Thank you!

Comment: @Don A side comment: although your setup (after fixing the transition matrix) was correct, it does not yield the exact answer. It only yields an extremely good approximation. This is because diagonalization winds up giving you $d_n = c_1 (-0.1)^n v_1 + c_2 v_2$, where $v_1,v_2$ are the left eigenvectors, $d_n$ is the distribution after $n$ days, and $c_1,c_2$ are constants depending on the initial condition. After long enough, the first term is much smaller than the second term. In this problem even 20 steps is plenty.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for the explanation. I think usually we are asked to give an estimated value of the probability, and the rate of convergence of P^n(i,j) to x_j is very quick :)

Comment: @Don In this case it is very quick, because the next eigenvalue is so much smaller in magnitude than $1$. My work recently has been with metastable systems, where (in the discrete time situation) the eigenvalue closest in magnitude to $1$ is actually very close to $1$. In this case the convergence is actually quite slow. So this convergence rate issue sticks with me when I think about problems like this.

Comment: @Ian I haven't studied metastable systems, but thank you, I'll keep that in mind.